# Quadratic Form on Exterior Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

So, I am doing this homework, and I got stuck at the very last question. Let me state the whole question, and provide solutions to those I already did:

Let $M$ be a free $R$-module of rank 4. Let $2$ be invertible in $R$ and consider the quadratic form $Q_M:\wedge^2(M)\rightarrow\wedge^4(M)$ such that $Q_M(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha\wedge\alpha)$.

So I was able to show that $Q_M(x\wedge y + u\wedge v) = x\wedge y\wedge u\wedge v$, for $x,y,u,v \in M$. Also, I have shown that if $Q_M(\sum_{i<j}a_{ij}e_i\wedge e_j) = q(\{a_{ij}\})e_1\wedge e_2\wedge e_3\wedge e_4$, then $q(\{a_{ij}\})=a_{12}a_{34} - a_{13}a_{24} + a_{14}a_{23}$.

The final question of this exercise is to show that for $\alpha\in\wedge^2(M), Q_M(\alpha)=0$ if and only if $\alpha = u\wedge v$ for some $u, v \in M$. Of course the direction when $\alpha = u\wedge v$ implying $Q_M(\alpha)=0$ is easy. Doing the converse seems to be my problem. And so that is my question, on how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Am I misunderstanding part 2? It looks to me like $e_1\wedge e_2+e_3\wedge e_4+ e_1\wedge e_3 +e_2\wedge e_4$ maps to $0$ if part 2 is right...oh oops, that factors as $(e_1-e_4)\wedge (e_2+e_3)$, sorry.

Comment: Actually, that's precisely my problem. I checked part 2, and it seems that my computation is indeed correct, which yields a counter-example to the last part, right? I am double checking it, but that's really what I'm getting...

Comment: Oh, OF COURSE it is $(e_1 - e_4)\wedge(e_2+e_3)$. I also oversaw that. =)

Comment: I hope I can get something more elegant than this:

Since $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ span $M$, then for some $a, b, c, d \in \wedge^1(M)=M$, we have $\alpha = -a\wedge e_1 - b\wedge e_2 - c\wedge e_3 - d\wedge e_4$, which yields 

$Q_M(\alpha)=a\wedge b\wedge e_1\wedge e_2 + a\wedge c\wedge e_1\wedge e_3 + a\wedge d\wedge e_1\wedge e_4 + b\wedge c\wedge e_2\wedge e_3 + b\wedge d\wedge e_2\wedge e_4 + c\wedge d\wedge e_3\wedge e_4$, and then argue that either three of $\{a, b, c, d\}$ are zero, or we get $\{a, b, c, d\} \in \{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$ with a proper choice.

Comment: In both cases we show that $\alpha = u\wedge v$ for some $u, v \in M$.

I don't know if I can write this in a more elegant manner...